# Tyk Ouath2 flow client_credentials ERROR: Couldn't use policy or key rules to create token, failing

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, tyk

I'm using Tyk 2.2.0 as an api management oauth2, basic, I need to add the `client_credentials` oauth2 flow as an `allowed_access_types`.
I made the following changes in order to generate an access token via this new oauth2 access type:

- Create a Tyk Api:

  ```
  {
  "name": "api_oauth_v2_oauth2",
  "api_id": "openApi",
  "org_id": "",
  "definition": {
      "location": "header",
      "key": "version"
  },
  "use_oauth2": true,
  "oauth_meta": {
      "allowed_access_types": [
          "authorization_code",
          "refresh_token",
          "client_credentials"
      ],
      "allowed_authorize_types": [
          "code",
          "token"
      ],
      "auth_login_redirect": "https://www.dev.docapost.io/dashboard/page/external/client/authorize"
  },

  "notifications": {
      "shared_secret": "",
      "oauth_on_keychange_url": "http://provisioning:8080/newton-provisioning-web/v1/external/notify"
  },

  "version_data": {
      "not_versioned": true,
      "versions": {
          "Default": {
              "name": "Default",
              "expires": "3000-01-02 15:04",
              "use_extended_paths": true,
              "extended_paths": {
                  "ignored": [],
                  "white_list": [
                              {"path":"/users/mobiles/{smartPhoneId}/{pushToken}","method_actions":{"PUT":{"action":"no_action"},"DELETE":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/users","method_actions":{"GET":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/objects/boxnumber/{boxNumber}/serialnumber/{serialNumber}","method_actions":{"PUT":{"action":"no_action"},"GET":{"action":"no_action"},"DELETE":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/objects","method_actions":{"POST":{"action":"no_action"},"GET":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/data/boxnumber/{boxNumber}/serialnumber/{serialNumber}/code/{code}","method_actions":{"GET":{"action":"no_action"},"POST":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/data","method_actions":{"POST":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/shares","method_actions":{"GET":{"action":"no_action"},"POST":{"action":"no_action"},"DELETE":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/subscriptions/preconditions","method_actions":{"GET":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/subscriptions/{id}/suspend","method_actions":{"PUT":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/subscriptions/{id}/configure","method_actions":{"PUT":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/subscriptions/{id}/resume","method_actions":{"PUT":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/subscriptions/{id}/cancel","method_actions":{"PUT":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/subscriptions","method_actions":{"POST":{"action":"no_action"},"GET":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/objectmodels/{id}/partnerUri","method_actions":{"PUT":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/objectmodels","method_actions":{"POST":{"action":"no_action"},"GET":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/action","method_actions":{"POST":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/organizations/repositories","method_actions":{"GET":{"action":"no_action"},"PUT":{"action":"no_action"},"DELETE":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/repositories/{repositoryName}","method_actions":{"GET":{"action":"no_action"},"DELETE":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/repositories","method_actions":{"PUT":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/buckets/boxnumber/{boxNumber}/serialnumber/{serialNumber}/code/{code}","method_actions":{"GET":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/offers","method_actions":{"GET":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/pictures","method_actions":{"GET":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/authentication/two-factor/code/{code}","method_actions":{"PUT":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/authentication/two-factor/code","method_actions":{"POST":{"action":"no_action"}}},                        
                              {"path":"/scripts/{serviceName}/{functionName}","method_actions":{"POST":{"action":"no_action"}}}                        ],
                  "black_list": []
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "proxy": {
      "listen_path": "/hub/v2/",
      "target_url": "http://mediation:8080/mediation-api/v2/",
      "strip_listen_path": true
  },

  "enable_batch_request_support": false
  ```

  }
- add tyk policy to this new api openApi:

  {
          "default": {
              "access_rights": {
                  "openApi": {
                      "allowed_urls": [],
                      "api_id": "openApi",
                      "api_name": "moussiApi",
                      "versions": [
                          "Default"
                      ]
                  }
              },
              "active": true,
              "name": "default",
              "rate": 100,
              "per": 1,
              "quota_max": 10000,
              "quota_renewal_rate": 3600,
              "tags": ["Startup Users"]
          }
      }
- modify tyk.conf to attach policies by adding this lines

  ```
  {"policies": {
  "policy_source": "file”,
  "policy_record_name": "./policies/policies.json"
  }
  ```

  }
- Reload Tyk configuration

  curl -X GET \
    http://localhost:8082/tyk/reload/ 
    -H 'x-tyk-authorization: 352d20ee67be67f6341b4c0605b044b8'
- Create new Oauth Client with new Api

  curl -X POST \
    http://localhost:8082/tyk/oauth/clients/create 
    -H 'content-type: application/json' 
    -H 'x-tyk-authorization: 352d20ee67be67f6341b4c0605b044b8' 
    -d '{
  "api_id": "openApi",
   "redirect_uri": "http://www.myuri.fr"
  }'
- generate Access Token:

  curl -X POST \ http://localhost:8082/hub/v2/oauth/token/  -H 'authorization: Basic MGFmYjBmYWUzYmZkNDNlZDQ0YzhjYTlkNWFiYWIwN2E6T0dKaU5qVXhZak10WXpObU9DMDBZVFkwTFRZME1HUXRabVZoT1dRMU1qTTBNalk0'  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  -d 'client_id=0afb0fae3bfd43ed44c8ca9d5abab07a&client_secret=OGJiNjUxYjMtYzNmOC00YTY0LTY0MGQtZmVhOWQ1MjM0MjY4&grant_type=client_credentials'

Unfortuanately I got this error while generating access token with `client_credentials` grant type:

> ```
> {"error":"server_error","error_description":"The authorization server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request."}
>
>
> time="Jan  8 13:29:53" level=info msg="Getting client ID:0afb0fae3bfd43ed44c8ca9d5abab07a" 
> time="Jan  8 13:29:54" level=info msg="[OAuth] Generating new token" 
> time="Jan  8 13:29:54" level=error msg="ERROR: Couldn't use policy or key rules to create token, failing"
> ```

- logs

> ```
> time="Jan 10 08:45:54" level=info msg="Initiating reload" 
> time="Jan 10 08:45:54" level=info msg="Reload URL Structure - Scheduled" 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="Loading API Specification from /USR/newtprod/tyk/apps/app_api_oauth_v2_oauth2.json" 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="Detected 1 APIs" 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="Loading API configurations." 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="--> Loading API: api_oauth_v2_oauth2" 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="----> Tracking: (no host)" 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="----> Checking security policy: OAuth" 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="----> Setting Listen Path: /hub/v2/" 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="Loading uptime tests..." 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="Initialised API Definitions" 
> time="Jan 10 08:46:04" level=info msg="API reload complete" 
> time="Jan 10 08:59:24" level=info msg="Getting client ID:14b2ac609a35405169ee3804db1ab406" 
> time="Jan 10 08:59:24" level=info msg="[OAuth] Generating new token" 
> time="Jan 10 08:59:24" level=error msg="ERROR: Couldn't use policy or key rules to create token, failing"
> ```

Any idea please.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have just completed a full authentication with this Oauth2 access flow.

> be attention you may have to restart the tyk service, a simple reload
>   does not load new policies into memory.

I illustrated this in an article that I posted a few days ago.

https://dzone.com/articles/tyk-management-api-oauth2-client-credentials-flow